# SQL Creating UDF Computed columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to create a computed column but since one of the column is in another table i understand that i need to create a udf. 
Here's a link to the ERD so you can see the relations

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/databaseassignment2new.png/

This is what im trying to do.

```
CheckOutDate + loanperiod = lastreturndate
So the result would look something like this

Checkoutdate    loanperiod      lastreturndate

2012-1-01          3         2012-4-01
```

This is what i have so far

```
  CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Getvaludates( @laastreturndate DATETIME)
  RETURNS DATETIME
  AS
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @lastReturndate DATETIME

  SELECT @lastReturndate= dateadd(month,loanperiod,CheckOutDate)
  FROM [Loan] I
    JOIN [Item] L ON I.barcode = L.barcode
    JOIN [Return] R ON I.barcode = R.barcode
   WHERE I.barcode = @lastreturndate
   RETURN @lastReturndate
   END 
   GO
```

AND I then i need to add this to the computed column

```
   ALTER TABLE dbo.Item
   ADD lastreturndate AS dbo.Getvaluedate(lastreturndate)
```

Comment: Hi Sebastian, try passing in barcode to your UDF instead of  lastreturndate.  You want to return the lastreturndate, not pass it in.  Then update your WHERE statement as well  See how that works.  Good luck.

Comment: @sgeddes Do i also have to pass barcode in  ADD lastreturndate AS dbo.Getvaluedate(here)

Comment: BTW -- where is your loanperiod field stored? Don't see it in your table defs.

Comment: @sgeddes in Item_Details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your UDF should look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Getvaluedate( @barcode int)
  RETURNS DATETIME
  AS
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @lastReturndate DATETIME

  SELECT @lastReturndate= dateadd(month,loanperiod,CheckOutDate)
  FROM [Loan] I
    JOIN [Item] L ON I.barcode = L.barcode
    JOIN [ItemDetails] ID ON L.isbn = ID.isbn
   WHERE I.barcode = @barcode

   RETURN @lastReturndate
   END ;
```

And then:

```
ALTER TABLE Loan ADD lastreturndate  AS dbo.Getvaluedate(barcode);
```

And here is a [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7089b/1)