# How can I explicitly define during the creation of a table a SELECT statement that grabs a specific piece of data from another existing table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've been struggling over this for a while now, I'm trying to define my table so that a specific column will use data sent in and stored in other columns to find data within a separate table and then store it in said column.

I've tried using stored procedures - wouldn't allow to me call the procedure in the following manner

```
[to] AS EXECUTE procName @parameter1 = [info],
                         @parameter2 = [info2],
                         @outputparmeter = @output OUTPUT
```

I've also tried to call functions but found that you couldn't use `SELECT` statements in relation to searching through a table inside a function. (<-- Not sure if this is entirely accurate, but from my extensive searching this is the conclusion I've come to, Feel free to correct me on it, or just clarify whether it's true or false as a statement).

Started searching after that and attempted to use a function calling a stored procedure, doing the search of the alternative table in the procedure, passing it back to the function which in turn passed it back to the column. This seemed to be okay until I executed my query at which point it blew up and told me that I can't have an `EXECUTE` statement within a function.

If you guys can shed any light on any of these issues and ideally a solution to my problem, I'd appreciate the help.

**EDIT :**

Table Users SAMPLE (Everything here works.)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Users
(
    [userId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [firstname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [lastname] [nvarchar](50)  NOT NULL,
    [dateOfBirth] [date] NOT NULL,
    [age] AS [dbo].getAge([dateOfBirth])
)
```

Table Messages SAMPLE (Herein Lies the problem)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].Messages
(
    [messageId] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [fromFirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [fromLastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [from] [int], --This needs to search for data within the Users table using the [fromFirstName] and [fromLastName] to get the userId for the specified user.
    [toFirstName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [toLastName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [to] [int],    --This needs to search for data within the Users table using the [toFirstName] and [toLastName] to get the userId for the specified user.
    [content] [nvarchar](999) NOT NULL,
    [dateSent] [date] DEFAULT GETDATE()
)
```

tried the following :

- Stored Procedure - unable to call the procedure as shown in the
  original post.
- User Defined Function - unable to use a SELECT    statement to get
  the data from Users table.
- User Defined Function    calling a Stored Procedure - unable to use
  EXECUTE statement within a    function?

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking.  Can you edit your question with a data sample from the two tables and the result you are looking for?

Comment: I'll give you what i can, Give me a few.

Comment: A table will not lookup data in another table by itself - you need some other mechanism, such as a stored procedure, to accomplish this.  I suggest removing fromFirstName, fromLastName, toFirstName, and toLastName from Messages.  Use a stored procedure to lookup the userID to populate the From and To fields in the Messages table.

Comment: Your Messages table only needs one way of identifying "from" and "to" users.  The best way to do that would be with the userID.  Otherwise what would happen if you had two "Bob Smith"s using your system?

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for the reply, Can you suggest a basic way of going about this? First off how and where would i call the stored procedure? furthermore, how would i specifically be able to target that specific entry from the procedure? Would it be best to use the messageId to target it? or is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Hi James, initially the table solely had the 'from' and 'to' columns, but as i struggled and i was trying to call procedures and functions from the column declaration i put them in to try and pass the names in.

Comment: Is your problem that you are trying to INSERT a record into Messages, given only the first/last names of the sender and receiver?  Or is it simply that you are looking for the best way to structure these tables for code that will come later?  I'm still not clear what you are trying to do that is tricky.

Comment: I'm not going to be implementing any code for this, this is solely practice with just SQL and SSMS, I want to INSERT a record, and when the Record is inserted for (what would happen in code is i would have a variable storing the name's or usernames of the people involved and then search through the users tables to find the id's of each individual and then store it in to [to] and [from]) the SQL Server to take the names and run a query to find the user Id of the names. Is there a way to do this in SQL or is it something best left for code?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand the code requirements behind this, but could you just have the Users table, the Messages table (without From and To), and then created a view on top of the Messages table that adds those columns using your query?

Comment: What *should* happen in code is a) you already know the user ID of the sender.  b)  You offer some kind of UI control with which the sender can uniquely identify the user ID of the recipient  c)  You insert a row into messages containing the message, the to id, the from id.  You should use your table to store atomic, non-repeated information.  Any reports or views use queries to make that atomic, non-repeated information understandable by a human (so, in a report you might replace ids with names, but the underlying table(s) just have ids).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per this [post](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2481/getting-creative-with-computed-columns-in-sql-server/) you can use a udf to fill in a calculated column and a udf can access other tables. I have not tested this functionality, perhaps this example will help expand upon your previous attempts. A related question seems to be using this technique: [SQL Creating UDF Computed columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058457/sql-creating-udf-computed-columns)

Quote:

> **Accessing a column outside of the computed column table**
>
> A computed column can not directly access any column outside its
>   table. This limitation may be overcome by using a User Defined
>   Function. A UDF may be used in the expression to access any column
>   outside the computed column table.

Comment: Thank you for the materials, will look into it and develop my use of UDF, but what i was doing is definitely better accomplished in code than in SQL.