# Specify a computed column in SQL Server 2012 as an average

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Can I specify a computed column in SQL Server that averages another column?

So for example

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Sales 
(
    TimeOfSale dateTime,
    AmountOfSale money,
    TotalSalesForMonth AS ?(Sum(AmountOfSale) over TimeofSale by month),
    AverageForMonth AS ?(Sum(AmountOfSale) over TimeofSale by month / # sales per month)
);
```

I'm sure I could do this as a stored procedure and make another table, but I'm just curious as to whether it is possible to do so with computed columns.

Comment: I didn't, I'm not sure what the computed columns would look like.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But to do that the computed column must be the result of a UDF. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058457/sql-creating-udf-computed-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this, but you would have to write a UDF that calculates the aggregations and call the UDF in the Computed column definition.

Be advised that while this can be done, it may not be the best idea:   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2011/11/28/a-computed-column-defined-with-a-user-defined-function-might-impact-query-performance/